# Entity Framework One-To-Many Delete relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, one-to-many

I have two entities `Transaction` and `DiscountType`

**Transaction:**

```
public class Transaction
{
    [Key]
    public int TransactionID { get; set; }
    public virtual DiscountType DiscountType { get; set; }
}
```

**DiscountType:**

```
public class DiscountType
{
    [Key]
    public int DiscountTypeID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
    public float DiscountValue { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled {get; set;}
}
```

**Relationship:**

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<DiscountType>().HasMany(d => d.Transactions);
```

**Aim:**

I am trying to remove the relationship between the Transaction and the DiscountType, without actually removing either entity.

**Problem:**

Now I'm having no problem assigning a Discount to a transaction, but when I do the following:

```
 var transaction = context.Transactions.Where(t => t.TransactionID == 1).First();
 transaction.DiscountType = context.DiscountTypes.Where(d => d.DiscountTypeID == 1).First();
 context.SaveChanges();


 var _transaction = context.Transactions.Where(t => t.TransactionID == 1).First();
 _transaction.DiscountType = null;
 context.SaveChanges();
```

It's quite a peculiar problem I'm having. When this code is ran it does not remove the relationship between the two.

**Actual Code:**

[image: As you can see, even after the <code>= null;</code> is executed, it still remains.]

As you can see, even after the `= null;` is executed, it still remains.

Comment: I'm a fan of foreign keys for those types of relationships.

Comment: Please elaborate. I'm new to EF.

Comment: Have you tried getting your DiscountType (via the context) and then calling .Remove(yourtransaction) on DiscountType.Transactions? I had to do this for EF because SaveChanges does not recognize changes to relationships - only scalar value changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think your select statement might need to be:

```
transaction.DiscountType = 
  context.DiscountTypes.Where(d => d.DiscountTypeID == 1).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: I wrote that for demonstration purposes. The point is, it works when it creates the relationship. But not when deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you better invert the relationship in the creation of the `DbContext`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>()
    .HasOptional(x => x.DiscountType)
    .WithOptionalPrincipal();
```

This creates a nullable foreign key to DiscountType in Transaction and I think it will allow you to set it to `null`.

(Personally I think it is a better way of putting it, because semantically it seems weird for a type to "have" Transactions, but a Transaction having a type is quite normal.)